# Will calling audio.play() pre-cache an HTML5 audio in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, preload

I have a bunch of audio clips that I need to repeatedly play in the browser.

As far as I understand doing `audio = new Audio(src)` does not do any IO on the actual source file until `audio.play()` is called.

Is there any guarantee that the code below would cache the audio in the browser and minimize latency?

```js
audio = new Audio(src);
audio.volume = 0;
audio.play();
```

Is there any downside to this approach apart from the fact that `volume=0` does not work in some Safari-based browsers, like the ones on IOS?

Is there a better approach for caching short audio clips?

Comment: what about `audio.play(); audio.pause();` the whole media may not be preloaded, but probably enough to reduce latency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try setting the `preload` attribute of the [audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) element as `auto` :

```
audio = new Audio(src);
audio.preload = 'auto';
```

Demo:

```js
var aud = new Audio('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Ludwig_van_Beethoven_-_Symphonie_5_c-moll_-_1._Allegro_con_brio.ogg')
aud.preload = 'auto'
var bData = document.createElement('span')
document.body.appendChild(bData)
setInterval(() => bData.innerText = 'Buffered Time(in seconds): ' + (aud.buffered.length && aud.buffered.end(0)), 300)
```

Comment: oh yeah, and the downside is extra HTTP calls made and extra bandwidth used.

Comment: Browsers are not forced to respect the preload attribute, and actually, I think that most mobile browsers just won't preload it.

Comment: @ccpizza,  I am not  using  a tag for  audio,  the tag is to show the progress of buffering,  can  be  ignored

Comment: @mido: How exactly are extra HTTP calls made? I'd assume that _if_ the browser fetched the audio when preload was set rather than on play, then no extra requests will happen when `play()` is called, so the difference is only in *when* the request is made and not in the number of requests, no?

Comment: @ccpizza i said extra because, what if user don't need all the audio you have downloaded